# Timeout doesn't clear on componentWillUnmount

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to set a timer when the component renders (componentDidMount),however, if the user finishes the given task before the time ends I want the timer to stop (in componentWillUnmount) but it won't. The alert pops up on other pages after the time ends.

```
class questionstest extends Component {
constructor(props) {
timer: null
};
componentDidMount() {
    this.beginTimer();
}
beginTimer() {
    this.setState({timer:setTimeout(() => alert("time end"), 100000)});
}
componentWillUnmount() {
    clearTimeout(this.timer)
}
```

note: tried to move the "clearTimeout(this.timer)" to the submit button but it didn't work, I also made sure that the "componentWillUnmount" is called.

note 2: If someone can also tell me how to start the timer after I get the data from the server that would be great.

Comment: in beginTimer function, please try this.timer = setTimeout(() => alert('time end', 100000))

Comment: It has to be `clearTimeout(this.state.timer)`.

Comment: timer doesn't need to be in state, I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `clearTimeout(this.state.timer)`.

Comment: Sure thing. It's important that you understand the difference. `setState` doesn't impact the class variable `timer` that you have defined (or any class variables, for that matter), it just changes the `state`

Answer (score 1):

Update your code as:

```
class questionstest extends Component {
constructor(props) {
 this.state = {
  timer: null
 }
}
componentDidMount() {
    this.beginTimer();
}
beginTimer() {
    this.setState({timer:setTimeout(() => alert("time end"), 100000)});
}
componentWillUnmount() {
    clearTimeout(this.state.timer)
}
}
```

Although, It seem like you don't require timer in state, as timer update is not required to update DOM, thus you can go with following solution as well:

```
    class questionstest extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
     this.timer = null;
    };
    componentDidMount() {
        this.beginTimer();
    }
    beginTimer() {
        this.timer = setTimeout(() => alert("time end"), 100000);
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearTimeout(this.timer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it's just like @Ron B. said, I didn't know I should use ".state"